Is the factor theorem for modules true for rings
I have already known a result from factor theorem for modules:
Theorem. For any $R$-module homomorphism $f: M \rightarrow N$, then $ M/\mathrm{ker} f \stackrel{\sim}{=} \mathrm{Im} f$.
Proof. Show that $\bar f: M/\mathrm{ker} f \rightarrow  \mathrm{Im} f, \bar x \mapsto f(x)$ is a module isomorphic. $\square$
I wonder if is there a simultaneous result for ring homomorphism.
That is if $f: M\rightarrow N$ is a ring homomorphism, is the corresponding $$\bar f: M/\mathrm{ker} f \rightarrow  \mathrm{Im} f, \quad \bar x \mapsto f(x)$$ a ring isomorphism or not. I applied the same way as the proof for module homomorphism and found out it "worked".
My proof.
For $\bar{x'} = \bar x \in M/\mathrm{ker}f$, $x-y\in \mathrm{ker}f$. Thus $f(x)=f(y)$ or $\bar f(\bar x') = \bar f(\bar x)$. Therefore $\bar f$ is truly a map.
We will show that $\bar f$ is a ring homomorphism. Indeed, forall $\bar x, \bar y\in M/\mathrm{ker}f$,
$$\bar f (\bar x + \bar y) = \bar f (\overline{x+y}) = f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y),$$
$$\bar f (\bar x . \bar y) = \bar f (\overline{xy}) = f(xy) = f(x)f(y).$$
Furthermore, $\bar f$ is monomorphic since
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{ker} \bar f &= \{ \bar x \in M/\mathrm{ker}f \;|\; \bar f(\bar x) = f(x)=0\}\\
&= \{ \bar x \in M/\mathrm{ker}f \;|\; x \in \mathrm {ker} f\} = \{\bar 0\}.
\end{align*}
For any $y \in \mathrm{Im} f$, $y=f(x)=\bar f(\bar x)$. Thus $\bar f$ is isomorphic. $\square$

Welcome to MSE. You write : "For $\bar{x'} = \bar x \in M/\mathrm{ker}f,x-y\in \mathrm{ker}f$". What is $y$?

Once you correct the couple typos with the $x'$ and the $y$, your proof works.

You want to make sure that you can really define a map by posing$$\boxed{\bar f(\bar x):=f(x)}(*)$$
Your problem is to make sure that if $x'$ is another representative of $\bar x$, then you'll get the same thing.
Let then $x'$ another representative of $\bar x$. By definition of $\bar x$,$$x'\in x+Ker f\iff \exists u\in Ker f , s.t. x'=x+u$$
For that representative $$f(x')=f(x+u)=f(x)+f(u)\text{ since f is an homomorphism}$$ $$=f(x)+0 \text{ since }u\in Ker f$$ $$=f(x)$$
Then the formula $(*)$ allows you to define a map.

Then, I would have written $$\bar f (\bar x + \bar y) = \bar f (\overline{x+y}) = f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)\color{blue}{=\bar f(\bar x)+\bar f(\bar x)}$$

The rest is ok. You "wonder if is there a simultaneous result for ring homomorphism." I let you conclude possibly with a little bit of openness here.
